# How to make a server daemon which re-runs automatically when they're terminated unexpectedly?

Tags: service, daemon

I'm trying to running OrientDB on Ubuntu. Currently, I'm running with `bin/server.sh`. This works fine except it runs foreground on shell. I can make it work background by `Ctrl+Z` and `bg` command, but this doesn't mean it's running as daemon.

I wish the program will keep running after I logout. And will be started again when it terminated unexpectedly or OS restarts. Like MS Windows Services. But the problem is I don't know how can I do this.

How can I run a program as a long-running service?

Comment: Concerning the quitting on logout, use [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not own the server, look into using the "screen" command.  It will allow you to run a command, detach from the console where the command is running, then log out while leaving it running.  You may reconnect to the running screen to see output or restart the script.  Here's more info about the screen command:
http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/

If you own the server, you should write an init script.  It's not very hard, and you can set it up to run automatically on startup.  The system will run the script with a "start" parameter when you want it to start, and a "stop" parameter when you want it to stop.  Here's more detailed information:
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html

If the command doesn't already detach from the console (run in daemon mode) then in the init script place the command in parenthesis to run in it's own shell.  You will not see any output unless you pipe it to a file within the parenthesis.

```
(bin/server.sh >> /var/log/server.log)
```